# C# - How to guarantee that a properties remains Get only over time?

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn

I'm implementing a piece of sensitive software and I can see a possible "failure point"/"security leak" IF in the future someone sticks a public `set` on a specific property.

Besides the obvious `//Do not make this property set operator public because of XYZ` are there other safeguards I can put in place to prevent such misguided change?

Comment: Write a test that uses reflection to verify that there is indeed not a setter on the property.

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? I. e. Why would adding a setter create a security leak?

Comment: You can write a code analyzer using [roslyn](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn) to enforce such a thing.

Comment: @NigelBess I actually solved the problem... and the fix was removing the setter... the property in question had to be properly disposed and replaced because it is a memory pinned property... just "setting" it lead to a memory leak and a security leak

Comment: @Leonardo why not add code in the setter that prevents the memory leak?

Comment: @NigelBess my first try... but not that simple... cascading effect was too bad and caused other bugs

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your exact design but as I understand from the comments, you're using property to return a resource that needs to be discarded properly with `using`. If somebody else sets the property the handle to the IDispoable is lost, so it's up to the GC's mercy to dispose it.

Don't use properties to return IDisposable's (or any other resource type hat needs to be explicitly disposed). Use a method instead. That way, the object reference wouldn't be cached in the class, but in the caller. So, caller would be responsible of disposing it. This prevents adding any other code to change the instance in your class, because caching isn't done there anymore.

You can only direct developers to the right direction with a design that describes its intent clearly.

Comment: I agree with you, but the amount of changes necessary is quite big... and its not only a matter of calling `Dispose()`, its way worse than that

Comment: @Leonardo Is it bigger than the cost of security/leak issues that'll happen from the design in the future? :) Jokes aside, isn't a code comment warning the future developer enough in that case?